# Stopping AVAudioplayer in different class

Tags: iphone, class, avaudioplayer

i have a trouble with stopping sound from one class in other one class. i Play sound in ViewDidLoad and then i have main class for app MainView where i want to stop the sound from ViewDIdLoad. I searched forums and didn found resolution. COuld You pleazse help me?

VievDidLoad is in the gdziedotykViewController.m

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"farmaglownaloop" ofType:@"mp3"];
startdzwiek = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
startdzwiek.numberOfLoops = -1;
[startdzwiek play];

- (void)stopping{
[startdzwiek stop];
```

}

and i want to stop sound in MainView.m class

```
gdziedotykAppDelegate *dzwiekdelegat = (gdziedotykAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [dzwiekdelegat stopping];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of your view controller. That would start a new `AVAudioPlayer` and stop it. Clearly, this cannot work.

Rather, you could either

1. Keep a reference of your existing view controller playing the sound by making it the delegate of the `MainView` and then simply call `[self.delegate stop];`.
2. Or you could manage the sound player in your app delegate, and simply notify the delegate from both classes with

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] start];` and
 `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] stop];`

where you have to implement `start` and `stop` in the app delegate.

Comment: ok, so i moved from viewDidLoad all about sound and moved it to appDelegate.h, then i write void for stopping sound also in appDelegate. then i paste [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] stop];. sound is topping but tehere is error :"stop not found in protocol"

Comment: ok, finally i made it. i edited my code above. many thanks. i moved to adddelegate.m void stopping and declaration of audio and then i edit MainView.m